# Truncate LDA topics

Tags: nlp, gensim, lda

I am training an LDA model. While I obtain decently interpretable topics (based on the top words), particular documents tend to load heavily on very "generic" topics rather than specialized ones -- even though the most frequent words in the document are specialized.

For example, I have a real estate report as a document. Top words by frequency are "rent", "reit", "growth". Now, I have a "specialized" topic with top words being exactly those three. However, the loading of the specialized topic is 9%, and 32% goes to a topic which is very diffuse and the top words are rather common.

How can I increase the weight of "specialized" topics? Is it possible to truncate topics such that I only include the top 10 words and assign zero probability to anything else? Is it desirable to do so?

I am using the `gensim` package. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want a very precise control over the topics which looks much more like clustering with a set of centroids chosen ahead of time than LDA which is generally not very deterministic and hence controllable.

One of the ways you can strive to achieve your goal with LDA is to filter more words out of the documents (same as you do with stopwords). Then the "rather common" words that go into one of the topics stop obscuring the LDA model creation process and you get more crisply delineated topics (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Removing the most common words is quite a common practice for preprocessing in topic modeling. Because topics are usually generated from the most frequent words, but usually these words are not very informative. You can also remove the most common words as a post-processing step (See [Pulling Out the Stops: Rethinking Stopword Removal for Topic Models](https://aclanthology.org/E17-2069/))

About having sparser word-topic distributions, you can use Non-negative Matrix Factorization (NMF) instead of LDA. If you adjust the sparsity parameters, you can get more spiked proportions of the topics. You can use [scikit-learn NMF's implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html).